# To overlay two buttons on Google map such that each button click shows different set of markers on the map. Can this be done?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I need to add two buttons that overlays on the google map such that each click shows a different set of markers on the map. Is this achievable or do I need to change the approach?

My Fragment code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment(){}

static final LatLng VELACHERY = new LatLng(12.9758, 80.2205);
static final LatLng TAMBARAM = new LatLng(12.9300, 80.1100);

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


  //creating Markers  
Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(VELACHERY)
                .title("Velachery"));
            Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(TAMBARAM)
                .title("Volunteer")
                .snippet("I am safe")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(VELACHERY, 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    //map.setOnMarkerClickListener(listener)





    return rootView;
}

public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    if (map != null) {
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .commit();
    }
}

}
```

My Fragment layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, it's possible.
2. You could use a MapView or MapFragment-SupportMapFragment in a FrameLayout with the layout that contains your two buttons
3. Use `OnMapReadyCallback` to get the Google Map instance getMap is deprecated - look for `getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)`
4. Handle View.OnClickListener for buttons
5. Each time a button is pressed call GoogleMap.clear(); then add the markers you need to display for the button that is pressed

Layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button A"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button B"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Code

```
buttonA = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
buttonA.setOnClickListener(this);
buttonB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
buttonB.setOnClickListener(this);
mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

Implement OnMapReadyCallback.onMapReady

```
@Override
public void onMapReady( GoogleMap googleMap )
{
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    //Do any other setup you would like here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info @Proveribo .I have changed my Relative layout to Frame layout but not able to view the buttons.?Also can you show me a sample of getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)

Comment: @AnilN.P I've added layout and Java code. Use MapView instead.